# A newbie's integration question - bearer token

Tags: integration, rest

I have two Salesforce orgs. First org has a REST web service, second org is calling the webservice.

**Webservice:**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Johnny')
global class WebServiceFactory {
    @HttpGet
    global static void getRecord() {
        List<JSONFactory> JSONs = new List<JSONFactory>();
        for(integer i = 0; i<15; i++){
            JSONs.add(new JSONFactory(i, 'Jan' + i, 'Test' + i));  
            }
            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(JSONs));
    }
}
```

**Client callout class:**

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<Object> restCallout(){
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://ability-data-6444-dev-ed.cs102.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Johnny');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer abcdef123456}');
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    List<Object> objs = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    return objs;
}
```

Right now I have to authenticate using terminal and curl command to get the session ID. Then I have to hardcode that Session ID into the class which is calling my REST service.

How to simplify the process so that I don't have to change the Session ID manually (becuase it expires) and so that the authorization happens automatically and provides me the Session ID which I can then dynamically pass into the client callout class?

Comment: This is standard stuff, covered completely in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm). Please consider searching documentation before posting such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The short answer

is that you need to use an OAuth 2.0 flow and a Connected App to get the access token (which you put into the `Authorization` header for your request with a value of `Bearer <token here>`. The space between "Bearer" and your token is important).

#### The longer answer

The various OAuth 2.0 flows can be broken down into two categories, "interactive" and "non-interactive" (or "headless").

Interactive flows (which describes most of them) require user interaction (a popup window for them to enter their credentials), and non-interactive flows don't. Non-interactive flows are what you'd use for server-to-server or programmatic communication.

Since your client code indicates that it might be used as part of a Aura component/LWC, it may be possible to use an interactive flow (if every possible user in your second org has login credentials in your first org). I get the feeling that you'd probably want to use a non-interactive flow here though.

The non-interactive flows are:

- Username-Password
- JWT Bearer

The Username-Password flow is mostly meant for testing/prototyping. It requires you to have a high level of trust and control over the client.

The JWT Bearer flow only requires 4 pieces of information

- The username (for a particular user in your target org) you want to use to execute the request as
- The Client Id from your connected app (in the target org)
- The login url (`https://login.salesforce.com` for production orgs, `https://test.salesforce.com` for sandboxes, or your custom url if using an Experience Cloud "site")
- An expiration time (in seconds since the unix epoch), just needs to be long enough for the token request to be processed by Salesforce (so something like `Datetime.today().addMinutes(1).getTime();`)

The catches with the JWT Bearer flow are that:

- You need to use a digital certificate (you can use the SSL cert for your company's site, or create your own "self-signed" certificate) to keep things secure so internet randos can't  exploit your org
- You need to go through an interactive flow that can give you a "refresh token" (typically, the "Web Server" flow) one time before you can start using the JWT flow

For that second point, you can do that through your browser, or though a program like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) (I have no affiliation with Postman).

It is also possible to use a "Named Credential" to handle making the callout to another org and managing the access/refresh tokens, though I find the documentation on that to be... not that great or helpful.

And at any rate, you'll also need to create a Remote Site Setting in your client org to be able to make callouts to an external resource (even if that resource is another Salesforce org).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!